# Category links based on request.user.is_staff

Tags: django, duplicates

I need some guide or help, how can I solve this problem.
So I would like to generating category links based on `request.user.is_staff`
Currently I can do this, but it's make some duplicated query.

The current method is the next,
I have a context processor which is generate the category links

```
def blog_category_links(request):

    context = dict()
    queryset = Post.objects.select_related('category').distinct()

    context['categories'] = set([post.category for post in queryset if post.is_public or request.user.is_staff])

    return context
```

It works fine all of the cases except one, when I'm visiting the blog index page.

The method nearly the same.

```
queryset = Post.objects.select_related('category').select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags').distinct()
...
posts = [post for post in queryset if post.is_public or request.user.is_staff]
return posts
```

With this solution if I didn't logged in I get 5 queries ~10ms time without duplication. If i logged in I get 7 queries ~12ms time with 2 duplicates (user query)

So I know it's not the best design for this. This is the reason why I would like ask some help.

Thanks

Update:

Here is my Category model

```
class Category(models.Model):
""" Category model."""

   name = models.CharField(_('category name'), max_length=50)
   slug = models.SlugField(_('category slug'), max_length=50, blank=True)
```

and here is my Post model:

```
class Post(ContentModel):
"""Post model."""

    STATUSES = Choices(
        (0, 'draft', _('draft')),
        (1, 'published', _('published')),
        (2, 'private', _('private')),
    )

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True},
                           null=True, related_name='blog_posts')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    title = models.CharField(_('post title'), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('post slug'), max_length=105, blank=True, unique=True)
    head_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', default='no-image')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES, default=STATUSES.draft, db_index=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('publication date'), default=timezone.now)
    comments = models.BooleanField(_('allow comments'), default=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(_('sum of views'), default=0)
    favs = models.IntegerField(_('sum of favourites'), default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'created')
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    objects = models.Manager()

    @property
    def is_public(self):
        if self.status is Post.STATUSES.published and not self.pub_date > timezone.now():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very inefficient way to do things. You should do the filtering in the database. The logic should be: give me all categories/posts, except if the user is not staff, in which case filter them to only give me public ones.

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
if not request.user.is_staff:
    categories = categories.filter(post__status=1, post__pub_date__gte=timezone.now())
```

...

```
posts = Post.objects.select_related('category').select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags')
if not request.user.is_staff:
    posts = posts.filter(status=1, pub_date__gte=timezone.now())
```

Comment: I'm update the question because I forget some information. Please check it.

Comment: You need to move the `is_public` logic into the query - see the updated code.

Comment: this query gives me empty all the time
categories.filter(post__status=1, post__pub_date__gte=timezone.now())